# Directive scope not updated on async

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This seems to be a fairly common question over here, but I can't seem to wrap my head around data binding with custom directives in Angular. I'm using 1.4.8, and this is the code that I have:

```
<p data-ng-show="!main.resolved">Loading...</p>

<my-directive data-ng-hide="!main.resolved"
              data-file-reads="main.reads"></my-directive>
```

The value of `main.reads` is retrieved via `$http` on my `MainCtrl`:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {
    this.resolved = false;
    this.currentTab = 0;

    $http.get('/my/api/call').then(res => {
      this.reads = res.data.file_reads;
      this.writes = res.data.file_writes;
      this.resolved = true;
    });

    $scope.$watch('main.reads', new => console.log(new)); // triggered twice
  }]);
```

Now, the code for my directive is just listening for changes on the `fileReads` attribute:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        fileReads: '='
      },
      template: '<div></div>',
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      controller: ['$scope', 'files', function($scope, files) {
        const controller = this;
        $scope.$watch('fileReads', function(newVal) {
          console.log(newVal); // only triggered once
        });
      }]
    };
  });
```

I'm only getting one `console.log` with the value of `undefined`. When the `$http` promise resolves and the value of `fileReads` is updated on the `MainCtrl`, I get no update on the directive controller.

Now, I've banged my head against the wall with this kind of problem enough times to have a suspicion that this is somehow related to `$scope.$apply` and the `$digest` cycle, but I'm not updating my scope from an external source or anything.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have yet to find more information about the specific reasons (and I'll be sure to edit this post when I do), but for now wrapping my watch expression in a function call did it (I also replaced my `$watch` with a `$watchCollection`, but that's just minor):

```
$scope.$watchCollection(() => this.fileReads, newVal => console.log(newVal));
```